# How does EF codefirst know which model class to create a table for?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I was not able to find the answer to this online - please link me if I've overlooked any resources.

I understand how Entity Framework's codefirst works.  The question is: how does EF know which model class to create a table for and which model class to just treat as a class?

For example, in the sample MVC4 application that comes from creating a new MVC project with VS 2012 Express Developer, there are classes (LocalPasswordModel, LoginModel, RegisterModel, etc) in the Account Model that have no tables, and EF knows not to generate tables for these classes.

How does EF know this?

Answer (score 7):

Entity Framework looks at your `DbContext` class, and creates a table for each `DbSet<T>` property that you define.

EF won't even see any class which is not referenced by the DbContext.

Comment: thanks for the awesomely quick response.  Newbie here, so please forgive if my questions are silly.  Is what you are referring to behind the scenes?  I understand that we can extend DBContext class and  do what you are referring to with our custom model classes, but I don't see (from visible code with the out of the box MVC4 application) how the LoginModel or RegisterModel from the AccountModels.cs avoids table creation with EF.

Comment: @9999bao: EF does not look at all of your classes; it just looks at the `DbSet`s in the `DbContext`.  Since the DbContext doesn't reference those classes, EF doesn't even see them.

Comment: @slaks The exception to this rule is entity types referenced by navigation properties which even if not listed in the context are turned into tables in SQL.

Comment: The second exception to the rule is that you can define entities with Fluent API: `modelBuilder.Entity<Order>();` Actually you don't need any `DbSet<T>` property at all to define an entity model. You can always reference a set by `context.Set<T>()` which is the same as exposing a `DbSet<T>` property as long as `T` is a known entity explicitly defined with either a `DbSet<T>` property or with Fluent API or reachable by navigation properties.